# Getting apt-key warning when trying to install Griddb

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Griddb on my WSL version: 22.04.2

using command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.3 multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list'
```

then I have executed this:

```
wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

but getting warning:

**Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).**

how to resolve this warning and how can I update it and what impact it may cause to Griddb?